# Why is DirichletCondition giving unphysical results for NDSolve of a gaussian wave function?

Tags: differential-equations

I define an exact gaussian wave function and then use NDSolve to obtain the numerical solution for this wavefunction. Then I add a DirichletCondition to make an impenetrable wall for the numerical gaussian wave function to bounce off. But the numerical solution then gives a distorted wave function well before the wave function even touches the impenetrable wall! Why?

```
(*Define a gaussian wavefunction*)
psi[x_, t_] := 
 E^(-(x^2/(256 + 2 I t))) Sqrt[1/(
  8 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] + 1/8 I Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] t)]
(*check the boundary conditions*)
psi[-600, 0] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[-600, 1000] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[600, 0] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[600, 1000] // N // Simplify // Chop
(*Plot the real part*)
t = 0;
Plot[Re[psi[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]
t = 500;
Plot[Re[psi[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]
t = 1000;
Plot[Re[psi[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]

(*Get numerical solution for the wavefunction*)
Clear[psins, psin, x, \
t]
psins = First[
  psin /. NDSolve[{I D[psin[x, t], {t, 1}] + 
       1/2 D[psin[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0, psin[x, 0] == psi[x, 0], 
     psin[-600, t] == 0, psin[600, t] == 0}, 
    psin, {x, -600, 600}, {t, 0, 1000}, MaxStepSize -> 1]]
(*Plot*)
t = 0;
Plot[Re[psins[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]
t = 500;
Plot[Re[psins[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]
t = 1000;
Plot[Re[psins[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]

(*Add DirichletCondition*)
Clear[psins, psin, x, t]
psins = First[
  psin /. NDSolve[{I D[psin[x, t], {t, 1}] + 
       1/2 D[psin[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0, psin[x, 0] == psi[x, 0], 
     psin[-600, t] == 0, 
     DirichletCondition[psin[x, t] == 0, x >= 400]}, 
    psin, {x, -600, 600}, {t, 0, 1000}, MaxStepSize -> 1]]
(*Plot*)
t = 0;
Plot[Re[psins[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]
t = 500;
Plot[Re[psins[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]
t = 1000;
Plot[Re[psins[x, t]], {x, -600, 600}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Your true Gaussian wavefunction is not 0 at `x > 400`, but in your final exercise, you are forcing it to be 0, so naturally that wavefn will be different than the others.

Comment: Please explain more. Aren't I forcing the numerical wavefunction `psin[x,t]` to be 0 at `x>400`, but not forcing the true gaussian wavefunction `psi[x,t]`  to be 0 at `x>400`?

Comment: You are changing the boundary conditions of the problem.  That is naturally going change the resulting wave function NDSolve returns.  You might want to check out the Olness Zimmerman notebooks in MathSource.  They give examples of reflected waves in their Quantum Mechanics notebooks.  They have updated versions on their web site.

Comment: Yes, changing the boundary conditions of the problem does change the resulting wave function NDSolve returns. That is what I want to happen. But  if I define the wave function to be a traveling gaussian at t=0, and this traveling gaussian does not interact with the changed boundary conditions until a time t>>0, I do not expect the resulting wave function NDSolve returns to be significantly different than the wavefunction I defined at t=0! I bought the Zimmerman and Olness book, and looked at the updated notebook versions on the web. But they only solve the time-independent Schroedinger eq'n.

Comment: Look at Z & O Quantum Mechanics notebook. Then look at Problem 3: Particle Hitting a Finite Step Potential, and Problem 4: Particle Propagating Towards a Rectangular Potential.

Comment: I looked at Problems 3 and 4 in Z&O ch.9. They both assume steady-state conditions, where the free wave functions are standing waves, and solve the time-independent Schroedinger equation. I am trying to solve the time-dependent Schroedinger equation for a localized traveling gaussian wavepacket that approaches a wall, hits the wall, and is reflected back from the wall. It is not a steady-state problem.

Comment: Those waves are constant shape unlike yours, but they are still moving with time. i.e traveling waves.  The main thing I wanted you to notice is that they do not have the waves going to 0 at the boundary the way you are doing.  Their reflected wave is just the mirror image of the wave that would be going past the boundary if the boundary was not there.  They are not changing the wave function by changing the boundary conditions of the problem the way you are.  MMa is not automatically going to give you a reflected wave.  You need to compute the original WF past the boundary and reverse it.

Comment: I would think your reflected wave would be your original wave for `x < -400` then x shifted by +800.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get the real part of psi to make it easier to plot.

```
psi[x_, t_] := E^(-(x^2/(256 + 2 I t))) Sqrt[1/(8 Sqrt[2 Pi] + 1/8 I Sqrt[Pi/2] t)]

$Assumptions = x \[Element] Reals && t > 0

Re[psi[x, t]] // Simplify // ComplexExpand

(*(2 2^(3/4) E^(-((256 x^2)/(4 t^2+65536))) Sin[1/2 Arg[128+I t]]
Sin[(2 t x^2)/(4 t^2+65536)])/(Pi^(1/4) (t^2+16384)^(1/4))+(2 2^(3/4)
E^(-((256 x^2)/(4 t^2+65536))) Cos[1/2 Arg[128+I t]] Cos[(2 t x^2)/(4
t^2+65536)])/(Pi^(1/4) (t^2+16384)^(1/4))*)

fn = % /. Arg[128 + I t] -> ArcTan[128, t] // Simplify
```

Compile it to make it faster.

```
psir = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {t, _Real}}, (
  2 2^(3/4) E^(-((64 x^2)/(t^2 + 16384)))
    Cos[(t x^2)/(2 t^2 + 32768) - 1/2 ArcTan[128, t]])/(
  Pi^(1/4) (t^2 + 16384)^(1/4))]
```

I had to copy the output of fn.  Compiling did not work using fn or %.  Then

```
gifs = Table[
   Plot[{psir[x, t], psir[x - 800, t]}, {x, -600, 400}, 
    PlotRange -> {-.1, .1}, PlotLabel -> "t" t, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[.01], 
      Line[{{400, -.1}, {400, .1}}]}], {t, 0, 10000, 250}];
ListAnimate[%]
```

[image]

The reflected wave is just the mirror image of the original wave equidistant across the boundary.

Comment: That looks close to right! The wave seems to be reflecting off the boundary condition at x=400. But the wave is not going to zero at the boundary condition at x=400.

Comment: Its just the method of images. I used to do the same thing in calculating the pressure in an oil reservoir from an oil well near a vertical fault. If you're a physics guy its like image charge near a condctor.